# Have some troubles with Laravel whereIn

Tags: sql, database, laravel

So, I am trying to execute:

```
$table = 'russian_names';
$nameType = 1;
$options = array(1, 2, 6);
$names = DB::table($table)
            ->where('name_type', $nameType)
            ->whereIn('options', $options)
            ->get();
```

Of course, I have a row in `russian_names`:

```
id: 1
name: Vito
name_type: 1
options: 1,2,3,6
short_description: Short description for Vito.
description: Full description for Vito.
```

But I always get an empty array. I tried to convert each element in `$options` to string, but still no result. Also, I tried to execute this query without `whereIn` and it works. And also, when I exucute

```
select * from `russian_names` where `name_type` = 1 and `options` in (1, 2, 6)
```

in phpmyadmin it works perfectly. Is there anything I am missing?

**UPD**: mysql query log showing me this log:

```
select * from `russian_names` where `name_type` = ? and `options` in (?, ?, ?)
```

Looks normaly, because

```
select * from `russian_names` where `name_type` = ?
```

Works fine and showing me array with result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> options: 1,2,3,6

`WHERE options IN (1, 2, 6)` means "find rows that have an `options` value of `1`, `2`, or `6`. It does *not* mean "magically figure out that `options` is a CSV string and act as if it's an array of data". You'll need to store the `options` in another fashion - most likely, a many-to-many sort of relationship.

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL's new `JSON` data type doesn't support `IN` queries yet. If you were in Postgres, you could do this with JSON columns.

Comment: Oh I got it. I mistakenly thought that it will find something like `like '%1%'` and etc. But it search for `options = 1` and that's why there is an empty array. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @VitoGravano Yeah, `WHERE options IN (1, 2, 6)` is basically just short for `WHERE (options=1 OR options=2 OR options=6)`.